# What is the English translation of "ich hau dich, du Nuss"?

Tags: german-to-english

While playing, my kid said "ich hau dich, du Nuss". What does it mean in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A literal translation is "I (will) hit you, you nut!".

That's also a quite close to a correct translation of the content.

Note that "Nuss" (literally "nut") is used here as a mild, non-specific insult, possibly implying mild stupidity. It does *not* mean a crazy person.

Comment: I think it comes from "taube Nuss" (a nutshell without content), implying a hollow void in the head where the brain should be.